# Is there a way to hide the text in the left hand column in Messages?

Tags: messages

I want to hide the text under the name of the contact in the Messages app. So in the example below, it would be the text that is below the name `Matt Brian`.

[image: Messages]

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just drag the divider to the left.  It will shrink that area so that all you see is the names, not any of the text.

[image]